# FlashAir: change the size of thumbnail images

Tags: flashair

Is it possible to control the thumbnail size from thumbnail.cgi? Or is this extracted from the EXIF thumbnail in the main image?

In the browser example (the last 2 images at the [bottom of the last tutorial page](https://flashair-developers.com/en/documents/tutorials/web/7/)) they suggest that different size files can be generated and downloaded

How is this achieved?

I was looking at LUA scripting on a file write, but not really sure where to start with that.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Got ur answer? Had same query.

Comment: Unfortunately not :(